# Java ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor running 15 milliseconds late / inconsistent time?

Tags: java, multithreading, time, threadpool

I'm new too this site so forgive me if I've posted this questions in the wrong place or something :)

I've been researching and creating test programs non-stop trying to figure out what might be going wrong with the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor I create.

**The Problem:**

When running the below test application the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduled to run at a fixed rate of 3 milliseconds runs chaotically with frequent spikes of greater than 15 milliseconds. It should execute at a rate of every 3 milliseconds.

**Interesting Details:**

The problem **only** occurs outside of the IDE, the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor runs as expected inside an IDE such as Netbeans or IntelliJ.

**Question:**

Why am I getting **very** inconsistent times using the Timer and ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor classes? The time between executions range from the expected 3 milliseconds per execution to frequent spikes of 15 milliseconds between execution.

**Configuration:**

Java 7 Update 5, IntelliJ IDE, Windows 7, Run from Command Prompt.

**Test App Demonstrating the Problem, make sure to use outside of an IDE to see the problem. This program will output times that are greater then the expected time between execution. Should be around 15 milliseconds instead of the expected 3.**

Thank you all for your help! :)

```
package testtime;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestTime extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTime().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(area);

    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public TestTime() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        area.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                area.setText("--Press anywhere to start--\n\n" +
                        "If time exceeds 3 milliseconds it will be printed here...\n\n" +
                        "------------------------------------\n\n");
                executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
                executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Loop(), 0L, 3L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                executor.shutdownNow();
            }
        });

        area.setLineWrap(true);
        area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        area.setText("--Press anywhere to start--");
        add(pane);
    }

    class Loop extends Thread {
        long time = 0L;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long timeTaken = System.nanoTime() - time;
            time = System.nanoTime();

            if(timeTaken > 3500000L) {
                area.append(timeTaken+"(nanoseconds)  -- "+(timeTaken/1000000L)+"(milliseconds)\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Upon testing with an IDE (Eclipse), I agree with your findings for that (the only flagged ones were 3-4ms)

Comment: Welcome to SO. +1 for a well-written question.

Comment: Thank you all :) @AlexColeman Thanks for testing. That's the same results I get in an IDE but outside of one running in a command prompt I get spikes greater then 15 milliseconds and that's way worse. Otherwise i'd just ignore the small time variations. I dont' know why they differ in and out of the IDE.

Comment: outside the ide - define the java switches you use. Within an IDE or outside doesn't tell much, the main difference would be debug link and captured in/out/err streams but what may make difference are the switches you run java with.

Comment: With the test app above I don't use any special command line arguments. But I can see how that could make a difference.

Comment: @neptune692 Are you using different Java versions or releases of a similar version in the IDE compared to command line?

Comment: Good point, No I don't think so, in the IDE it uses `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\java` I have the jdk in my PATH environmental variable for Windows. Just in case that doesn't do it I tried running the app from the command line like this: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\java" -jar SpeedTest.jar` I assume that would make sure it uses the same exact version?

Comment: Do you have other versions of Java on your machine? If you do try to, via command line, compile in the other versions and see if it happens while running only on one other version. For instance I compiled your example in Java 6 and ran with Java 7 (command line) and saw noticeable difference. However when I ran in Java 6 through command line it seemed more stable. Though it could have been just a coincidence

Comment: I tried compiling with the following command `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\javac"` and running with the following, `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\java"` Assuming I'm doing this correctly I didn't notice much of a difference I still get frequent 15 millisecond spikes. I thought it might have made a difference at first but an IDE version of the app was running at the same time and for who knows why that fixes the problem in the command line app and brings the spikes down to 1 millisecond differences.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your problem comes from the garbage collector, which periodically freezes the process to remove unused objects from memory.

The JVM supports several different [GC algorithms](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html#1.1.%20Types%20of%20Collectors%7Coutline). There is a tradeoff between latency and throughput.

It's possible that IntelliJ uses a low pause GC to favor UI quick response, while the JVM defaults to high throughput outside of the IDE.

Can you try adding the `-Xincgc` option (to select Concurrent Mark&Sweep) to your project ?

Comment: I'd agree with the assessment that it might be a GC issue.

Comment: This was very promising however after running it in Command Prompt with the added command it doesn't seem too fix the issue. I thought at first it did but I tested it incorrectly inside an IDE and not in the Command Prompt. The ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor still has frequent spikes of 15 milliseconds when its supposed to be 3. I'd ignore it if it wasn't such a big variation and wasn't fixed when running in an IDE, which is odd. Thank you for the answer though :)

Comment: On another note I didn't try to add the command to the IDE because for some reason the problem **doesn't** occur inside the IDE I tried it in the command prompt `java -Xincgc -jar SpeedTest.jar` and got the same results. Want even more weirdness, the problem is fixed run from the Command Prompt if I run from the IDE while running the compiled desktop version. So if an app from the IDE is running at the same time the problem goes away in the desktop version run from the command prompt.... The 15 millisecond spikes disappear... I don't even know where to begin with that fact.

Comment: Can you see the command line used to start the process from the IDE ? With "ps aux" or something ? Is there a special option ?

Comment: Can anyone verify they also get this problem outside of an IDE? Inside it ranges by only 1 milliseconds, perfectly acceptable but outside it spikes to 15 milliseconds which is way off :/ If you do test it just make sure the IDE version isn't running at the same time cause that fixes it somehow.

Comment: Found a way to print the command line arguments the IDE is using `-XX:InitialHeapSize=133547264 -XX:MaxHeapSize=2136756224 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:-UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation -XX:+UseParallelGC` I used these in the Command Prompt but made no difference :/

Answer (score 1):

I think the Windows timer simply doesn't have such a fine resolution. You find more on that topic if you Google http://www.google.de/search?q=windows+timer+resolution

Comment: I'd +1, but I recall a colleague doing tests which show that the low resolution timer issue in Windows is fixed in Win7 and possibly Vista.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the contract specified by the Timer and ScheduledExecutor interfaces do not guarantee that the tasks will execute exactly at the interval specified. They simply promise not to run them any sooner than the interval.